# Load web page through html img?

Tags: html

I have a PHP file that I'm trying to get to load via an image tag:

```
<img src="https://example.com/tracker/">
```

I can see in Firebug that the PHP page is technically being loaded.  But since it's not actually an image, it looks like not everything from that page is running - like Javascript that's supposed to run tracking certain visitors.

I'm probably just going to add all the javascript and stuff into the footer of each page instead, but I still don't understand why this didn't work.

Didn't affiliates used to load web pages as images for cookie stuffing like 10 years ago?  I was under the impression that the page itself should load when being called, even as an image.

Or is it not loading as a result of some sort of browser security setting?

Comment: You can specify that the PHP file is an image with `header('Content-type:image/png');`. Then you can load it as a single pixel transparent image and still extract your user information.

Comment: But even when doing that, it doesn't look like FireFox is getting the HTML or javascript that's output on the page.  Right?  For example, if I output Google Analytics on that page, it's not actually executing the javascript...

Comment: Of course you can't run JavaScript "inside" an image. It's an image. _"Or is it not loading as a result of some sort of browser security setting?"_ - of course it is, because the failure to treat resources properly has endangered Internet Explorer users for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading an image that way won't treat the result as HTML and certainly won't try to run any javascript in it.

What that *is* good for is that /tracker/ can be a web application that does something with the request.  Instead of just retrieving an image, it can increment a hit count or inspect a cookie. Then it can return an image of some kind, even if it's a 1x1 transparent PNG.

If you want to execute Javascript, then use a Script tag instead.